# What does $-\pi < \theta < \pi$ mean?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

When I was asked to provide an angle in the interval $-\pi < \theta < \pi$, I said $\frac{3\pi}{4}$ since this is obviously less than $\pi$, but apparently it is not greater than $-\pi$ ($\frac{3\pi}{4}$ is not a valid choice for an angle in this interval for reasons unknown to me)? I don't understand.

Comment: ....Why is it not?

Comment: Do you have some more information about the question? All the information you give us says that you chose correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the question is not "What angles are **not** in the interval $-\pi<\theta<\pi$?" That would at least have some element of intrigue. The question must not be posed correctly; otherwise, your answer is perfectly fine.

Comment: It is given that we only take angles in the interval $-\pi < \theta < \pi$, and I was asked to find $\theta$ for $\cos\theta = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and I said $\frac{3\pi}{4}$, but I was marked incorrect and the correct answer is $-\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Your instructor/grader could have made an error and inadvertently considered $\sin(\theta)$ instead.